# jQuery .val() not working for input fields

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm trying to capture value of my input fields and have following method in my form class to do that:

```
getData: function() {
    var fields = ['name', 'email', 'message'];
    $.each(fields, function(index, el) {
        form.data[el] = $('#'+el).val();
        console.log(form.data[el]);
    });
},
```

(nevermind the 'select' field, that's a custom made select box and I'll have to handle that one differently)
I perform the capture on form change event.
The input fields all have proper id's, they look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="email" id="email">
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
```

Now, when I type something in the fields I only get value from the textarea, while other inputs give me undefined.

I'll also note that the form is being loaded with Ajax, but since it captures the change event on the fields normally I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: confirm that you don't have any other elements with duplicate id causing issues - because that *should* work.

Comment: yes ofcourse , `form.data[el] = $('#'+el).val();` this statement needs actually maps via `name` attr. anyway close the question with self answer.

Comment: To add to @NickDickinson-Wilde - I just had an instance where there was existing logic updating the input field via jQuery. This is probably a good thing to check as well, once I placed the new .val() logic after the existing logic it started working.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have figured it out.

I was missing the name attribute on my input fields and for some reason .val() needed that to work.

Comment: This worked for me as well, I would appreciate it if someone could explain *why* though.

Comment: According to W3C recommendations, an html for can only send data if the input field has a control name. Ids do not count. [https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

Answer (score 11):

"According to **W3C** recommendations, an html for can only send data if the input field has a control name. Ids do not count." Well, that is all fine and good (priceless, in fact) but `jQuery .val()` would have one believe it can happily use the `id=` as a selector if you look at [this example](http://api.jquery.com/val/). My testing showed not only does one have to have `id=` and `name=` but they have to be the same. I so love this stuff when it works!

Answer (score 4):

No, You do not have to have both name and id attribute for val to work. 
I had test it, with only id , .val() works fine

Comment: Perhaps the behaviour of .val() has changed in the recent jQuery versions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @nick-dickinson-wilde for your comment.
I had the same problem.  I wanted to get the value of the following input.

`<input id="ipValue" class="form-control" type="text" value="@Model.IPValue" />`

I was surprised the following did not work.

`javascript var ipValue = $("#ipValue").val();`

I didn't notice I had an element with the same id `<div class="col-3" id="ipValue">`

Answer (score 1):

the most stupid debugging I have ever had. After 3 days of looking for issues, I found that a link to jquery lib is missing. Unbelievable :D

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>`