# Using Jquery .val() cannot get number value from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to use jquery syntax to get number value from input field, but it does not work, the console did not show input value. Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = $("#a").val();
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="number">
```

Comment: i mean... What IS the input's value?

Comment: it does show it, it's just empty, try with `<input id="a" type="number" value="123">`

Comment: if you want whatever you type to show up as you type, you need to tie the input to an onkeyup event.

Comment: Yup, I mean when you input a random number value in the input field, the console log does not show that number value.

Comment: Read some beginner tutorials on interacting with the DOM in JS. You'll learn how to wire up functionality to events caused by page interaction. And better to learn the native API instead of an old, large library like jQuery.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms so you mean i have to include it in a button or something like that to invoke it? Otherwise it won't be shown?

Comment: You need to code it so that it prints the number whenever the value changes. The script can't know that's what you want to do.

Comment: https://javascript.info/keyboard-events

Comment: No need to downvote the question just because they are a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Add name="a" to your input element =>

See this for more information: [jQuery .val() not working for input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407017/jquery-val-not-working-for-input-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a document.Ready() event, the input value when the page loads is empty.  If you want to update the console with the value when a user types a number, then you must bind the user event, such as with a .keyup() event:

```js
    $("#a").keyup(function() {
        console.log($("#a").val());
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="number">
```